# Swapping Divs by their class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen a lot of questions similar to this but none that I could find address this specific problem or so I think.

I have a page built in this format that controls the concent of a dynamic part of a webpage, What i want it to do is with randomly based on the 
div with the "switchme" class. so basically I want everything to swap around without having the content inside the "switchme" change, just its place in the page. Ive tried numerous javascript and jquery scripts but in the end it always ends up moving around the interal divs

```
<div class= "switchme_container">
<div class = "switchme">
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
</div>
<div class = "switchme">
<div>Content</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class = "switchme">
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
<div>Content</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
function shuffle(sj) {              
var replace = $('<div>');
var size = sj.size();

while (size >= 1) {
   var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * size);
   var tempdiv = sj.get(randomize);      
   replace.append(tempdiv);        
   sj = sj.not(tempdiv); 

}
$('#switchme_container').html(replace.html() );   
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post one of the things that you have tried?

Comment: thats just one of many, ive also tried messing with the tags so their is only one div, but that really kills the styles i have

Comment: I'm not sure "swapping" is actually what you intend... could you clarify a bit?  Do you want to copy the contents of a random switchme into the "replace" div?

Comment: Can you provide an example of _shuffled_ markup?

Comment: each switch me is a slide in a banner, the first being the one that appears first, and i need them a random one to start not just the first each time

Comment: Did you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/D2jxe/1/

Comment: You don't appear to be setting `size` within the loop... does that loop actually terminate?

Comment: Where's the second closing brace?

Comment: @pedroestrada yeah soomething that on load keeps them all together but shuffles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the `switchme` elements into an array, shuffle them in a more obvious way, then push them back into the `switchme_container` element:

```
var shuffle = function(o){ //v1.0
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
$(".switchme_container").append(shuffle($.makeArray($(".switchme"))));
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2jxe/2/

jQuery automatically moves each element instead of copying it, unless you explicitly clone it before inserting it.

Shuffle function copied from here: [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for moving something is pretty simple:

```
 $newParent.append($thingToMove);
```

(NOTE: If you want to ditch the events handlers/data on `$thingToMove` you can call `.remove()` on it first.)

If that isn't working for you, you have a debugging problem to solve, but that should generally work.

Comment: You don't even need `.remove()`. In fact, `.remove()` removes event handlers and data.

Comment: Excellent point; I wasn't sure if remove was needed or not (and figured "it never hurts to clean up"); I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've attached the randomize event to a button click, answer embedded within the comments of the following code:

```
​$('#randomize').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var $sc = $('.switchme_container'),
        contentHolder = [],
        randomIndex;

    // detach .switchme elements from page and add to contentHolder array
    $sc.find('.switchme').each(function(i, el){
        contentHolder.push($(this).detach());
    });

    while (contentHolder.length) {

        // pick a random index of the contentHolder array
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * contentHolder.length);

        // append it to the container
        $sc.append(contentHolder[randomIndex]);

        // slice that element out of the contentHolder array
        contentHolder = contentHolder.slice(0, randomIndex)
            .concat(contentHolder.slice(randomIndex + 1, contentHolder.length));
    }
});​​​​​​
```

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ2PM/)